# How to sum values for each unique group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

In the dataset below, I want to identify `Top 3`  time-consuming projects

```
library(dplyr)
TransID <-c(1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008,1009,1010,1011,1014,1018,1022,1023,1024)
EmpID<-c('M001','M001','M001','M001','B005','B005','B005','B005','X101','X101','X101','Z101','K501','K501','K501','K501')
ProjectID <- c(200,200,200,200,500,500,500,500,950,950,950,950,1050,1050,1050,1050)
Site<-c('X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Z','Z','Z','G','G','G','G','K','K','K')
Region <-c('NE','NW','SE','SW','MW','NW','SW','NE','NC','MW','NE','SE','SW','NC','SW','SE')
hour_difference<-c(1.45,2.14,2.53,3.69,1.73,2.47,3.63,1.59,0.75,1.18,2.78,9.55,1.85,2.39,5.52,0.23)

df = data.frame(TransID,EmpID,ProjectID,Site,Region,hour_difference)
df
```

Simply,

1. for each unique `ProjectID`, I want to sum the `hour_difference` and `sort` in descending order

My attempt:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ProjectID,hour_difference) %>%
  summarize(sum().sort_values())
```

Desired output:

for example, `ProjectID = 950` will have a sum of `14.26`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Comment: Are you coming to R from Python or another language? R generally doesn't have syntax like `sum().sort_values()`

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about descending order of `ProjectID` or sum of `hour_difference` but you may try

## `sum(hour_difference)`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ProjectID) %>%
  summarise(res = sum(hour_difference)) %>%
  arrange(desc(res))

  ProjectID   res
      <dbl> <dbl>
1       950 14.3 
2      1050  9.99
3       200  9.81
4       500  9.42
```

## `ProjectID`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ProjectID) %>%
  summarise(res = sum(hour_difference)) %>%
  arrange(desc(ProjectID))

  ProjectID   res
      <dbl> <dbl>
1      1050  9.99
2       950 14.3 
3       500  9.42
4       200  9.81
```